# SceneDelegate function is never called

Tags: swift, swiftui, lifecycle, info.plist, uiscenedelegate

I have a SwiftUI/SpriteKit project. In an error-laden quest to change the bundle identifier, I decided to create a *new* project and copy my files over.

Now I've got this new project with all my old files but when I run it, I get a blank screen because my `SceneDelegate` function `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` is not being called.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/specifying_the_scenes_your_app_supports), a `SceneDelegate` setup will work if you make the appropriate changes to your `info.plist`. However, I've made those changes, and my `SceneDelegate` remains inoperative.

In my `info.plist`, I have the following:
[image]

Here's the relevant part of my `SceneDelegate`:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    
    static var mainData = MainData()

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(SceneDelegate.mainData))
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }

    //...more stuff here
}
```

**Question:**
Why isn't my `SceneDelegate` working? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: what you get in debugger window while launching app?

Comment: Are you migrating from AppDelegate or the new App lifecycle?

Comment: @RB's I get nothing in the logs, actually.

Comment: @aheze Migrating from AppDelegate

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I have no idea why my `SceneDelegate` wasn't working, but I did two things:

1. Deleted the app from the simulator I was using.
2. Restarted Xcode.

My `SceneDelegate` now works as expected.

Comment: wow - restarting XCode did the trick ... *sigh*

Comment: Thank you for this, I was going crazy why it's not working. Xcode is being Xcode again

Comment: just delete & reinstall works for me, thanks bro